# PDF page manipulation, from 2 page per sheet to one page per sheet

Tags: pdf, automation

I have a PDF with following pattern:

[image]

I need to transform each page of this PDF into two distinct pages, as follows:

[image]

and

[image]

So, if I had a PDF with 12 pages (2 slides for each page) I will expect a new PDF with 24 pages (1 slide for each page).

How do I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your pdf in Preview.app. Click the toolbox icon. Click the Rectangular-Select icon. Select one of the pages. Copy it. Click File > New from clipboard. Save that file. Repeat. Now you have Untitled1 through Untitled24. Open Untitled1 in Preview. Click the menu just under the red x and choose "Thumbnails."  Drag all the files Untitled2-24 just under Untitled1 in the sidebar. Save as a pdf.

Comment: This solved the problem I asked. Thank you. But I haven't specified how to have an "automated" mechanism to do that: how much time I will have to spent to transform 9 documents having between 24 ÷ 87 pages?

Comment: You may be able to automate the process with Briss. http://briss.sourceforge.net. It's what I use for problems such as yours, when I scan a book open faced and then want it in single pages. Sorry for not mentioning it the first time.